# Primeng don't import card component

Tags: angular, npm, primeng, angular-module

I would use Primeng Card component

In **module.ts** I call the module.

```
 import { CardModule } from 'primeng/card';
```

when compiling, angular don't find the module

```
 ERROR in /home/haddad/projects/arrr/arrrt/src/app/app.module.ts (9,28): Cannot find module 'primeng/card'.
```

I'm using the version **4.2.4**

when I update to version 5  of primeng I get this error

```
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /home/haddad/projects/node_modules/primeng/components/sidebar/card.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/haddad/projects/ar/arrt/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/haddad/projects/ar/arrt/src/app/app.module.ts
```

And I'm obliged to use angular 4.

Here's my **package.json** for more informations :

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
  "@angular/common": "^4.4.4",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.4",
  "@angular/core": "^4.4.4",
  "@angular/forms": "^4.4.4",
  "@angular/http": "^4.4.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.4",
  "@angular/router": "^4.4.4",
  "core-js": "^2.4.2",
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
  "primeng": "^4.2.4",
  "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "1.6.6",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.3.4",
  "@angular/language-service": "^4.3.4",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
  "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
  "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "~2.0.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~5.1.2",
  "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
  "tslint": "~5.9.1",
  "typescript": "~2.3.4"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 4 hours searching on the internet I realize that is not possible to use Card component with Angular 4.

Card component what create at PrimeNg 5.0.2 release : [card new component](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4535)

And PrimeNg 5.0.0 and above is not compatible with angular 4: [PrimeNg blog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5-0-0-released/)

> Angular 5 Support
>
> PrimeNG 5 fully support Angular 5, if your project is on Angular 4,
>   the PrimeNG version to use would be 4.x as PrimeNG 5 does not work on
>   Angular 4 due to AOT constraints.

It's necessary to update Angular version to 5.

Answer (score 0):

To import card module try below import statement:

```
 import { CardModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
```

Comment: get this error `ERROR in /home/haddad/projects/arrr/arrrt/src/app/app.module.ts (9,10): Module '"/home/haddad/projects/arrr/arrrt/node_modules/primeng/primeng"' has no exported member 'CardModule'.`
was card component  already included in 4.2.4 ?